# wxpython, to scroll a webView

Tags: wxpython

I built a webView as `wv=wx.html2.WebView.New(myFrame)`, and I used `wv.setPage(content, "")` to put a string of html text, it shows well and it has a scroll bar on side, since the content is more than the window can show.

Now I wish to control the webView and scroll it programmatically, (for example, let it scroll a line every 10s). I tried to use `wv.ScrollLines(1)` or `wv.ScrollWindow(1, 1)` but they had no response. Also `wv.GetScrollRange(0)`, `wv.GetScrollRange(0)` gave me 0, even `wv.HasScrollbar(wx.VERTICAL)` returned a False. And I tried looking up webView's document and didn't find any other scroll related attributes or functions.

Could you help me on this issue? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess `HasScrollbar` returns `False` because as a wx Window, it does not have a scroll bar; document has the scroll bar. As for how to scroll, there are two options you can take:

1) Use the method [Find](http://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/html2.WebView.html#html2.WebView.Find). This will search text and if found scroll to that position. You can for instance use a wx.Timer and using `Find` scroll to the next position:

```
import wx
import wx.html2

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "Scroll", size=(500,500))
        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self._on_timer, self.timer)
        self.wv=wx.html2.WebView.New(self)
        self.wv.SetPage(content, "")
        self.timer.Start(100) # adjust the timer interval
    def _on_timer(self, event):
        self.wv.Find("Some string in the text")

app = wx.App()
frame = MyFrame()
frame.Show()
app.MainLoop()
```

2) Use javascript for performing scrolls within the document, see [scrollTo](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_scrollto.asp).

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping! I guess I can use `self.wv.RunScript('scrollTo(%d, %d)' % (xPos, yPos))`.